# svn cannot access URL with a @ in it

Tags: svn, pycharm

I used PyCharm to rename a branch of my project : I asked to rename my branch v4.0.0 to v5.0.0  and I do not know why, but PyCham added a `@` in the destination name. I got this :

```
svn ls svn+ssh://svn@devhost/myproject/branches/
v2.0.0/
v3.0.0/
v5.0.0@/   <----
```

Now if I try to list files in this branch I get :

```
svn ls svn+ssh://svn@devhost/myproject/branches/v5.0.0@/
svn: warning: W160013: URL 'svn+ssh://svn@devhost/myproject/branches/v5.0.0' non-existent in revision 15667
svn: E200009: Could not list all targets because some targets don't exist
```

I tried without the `@`, or with a `%40` instead : I have the same message.
I tried the `-r <some revision>` option to see whether it is a revision problem, but it did not help.
I tried to use PyCharm again to rename `v5.0.0@` to `v5.0.0` : it tells I cannot rename to itself.
I tried to use PyCharm again to rename `v5.0.0@` to `v4.0.0` : it renamed that `v4.0.0@` with a `@` again.

The funny thing is that pycharm is still able to brower inside `svn+ssh://svn@devhost/myproject/branches/v5.0.0@/`

On my terminal, the `svn ls` does not work, the `svn co` also ! I cannot create a working copy myself !

The question : How can I rename branch `v5.0.0@` to `v5.0.0` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you know the `@` means "peg and operative revisions" in subversion - it's the reason of "unexpected" behavior. If you need use in filename you should double it:

```
svn ls svn+ssh://svn@devhost/myproject/branches/v5.0.0@@/
# or remove the @ char
svn mv svn+ssh://svn@devhost/myproject/branches/v5.0.0{@@,}/
```

See in the [SVNbook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/)'s [Peg and Operative Revisions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.pegrevs.html) chapter:

> This workaround even applies to paths that end in an at sign—you would
>   use `filename@@` to talk about a file named *filename@*.

It works on working copy too.